# Where can I buy heavy-duty Omni Wheels?

Tags: wheel

### Where can I buy multi-directional omni wheels?

I'm specifically looking at something which can support in **excess of 100kg/wheel, so around 400kg in total**. Also, a possible mission profile would include a 300 meter excursion outdoors on asphalt path, so they should be a little durable. The only ones I can find online are small ones for experimenting.

[image: pic]

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try andymark, their 10 inch mecanums (or smaller) may suit you well.

Answer (score 0):

Have seen in-action omni wheel industrial fork lift trucks like these image search.
https://www.google.com/search?q=omni+wheels+folk+truck&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=aiqhU8DwDdWhugTy_oCIBA&ved=0CCoQsAQ&biw=1654&bih=813  Apparently, they are production items, although may not as widely used as the 'normal' wheel version